# I use navigationlink and I also want to use side menu

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, navigation

I have a NavigationView component in my iOS app that's built with SwiftUI.

I use navigationlink to change my page.In the second screen, I want to  show side menu.But now I havetwo layers NavigationView in my iOS app, it's not my want to show.I  want the second screen only have side menu.

is it possible or am i missing something about the way navigation is being managed in Swift?

How should I change my code?

here's my ContentView.swift:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: SwiftUIView_map(),
                    label: {
                        Text("Skip")
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                            .font(.title)
                            .padding()
                            .background(Color.purple)
                            .cornerRadius(20)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                    })
                HeaderView()
                    .offset(y:-60)
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: Text("Login"),
                    label: {
                        Text("Login")
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                            .font(.title)
                            .padding()
                            .background(Color.purple)
                            .cornerRadius(20)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                    })
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: Text("Sign up"),
                    label: {
                        Text("Sign up")
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                            .font(.title)
                            .padding()
                            .background(Color.purple)
                            .cornerRadius(20)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                    })
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}


struct HeaderView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 2){
            Text("Just")
                .font(.system(size: 60,weight:.heavy,design:.rounded))
                .fontWeight(.black)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
            Text("test")
                .font(.system(size: 60,weight:.heavy,design:.rounded))
                .fontWeight(.black)
        }
        Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

The navigation sidebar:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SwiftUIView_map: View {
    @State private var isShowing = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            ZStack{
                if isShowing{
                    SideMenuView(isShowing: $isShowing)
                }
                HomeView()
                    .cornerRadius(isShowing ? 20 : 10 )
                    .offset(x: isShowing ? 300 : 0,y:isShowing ? 44 :0)
                    .scaleEffect(isShowing ? 0.8 : 1)
                    .navigationBarItems(leading: Button(action: {
                        withAnimation(.spring()){
                            isShowing.toggle()
                        }
                    }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "list.bullet")
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                    }))
                    .navigationTitle("home")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SwiftUIView_map_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SwiftUIView_map()
    }
}

struct HomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Color(.white)
            Text(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/"Hello, World!"/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

If you want more detailed code, please click the link
https://github.com/simpson0826/swifttest.git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `NavigationView` only in ContentView(root view).

```
struct SwiftUIView_map: View {
    @State private var isShowing = false
    var body: some View {
//        NavigationView{
            ZStack{
                if isShowing{
                    SideMenuView(isShowing: $isShowing)
                }
                HomeView()
                    .cornerRadius(isShowing ? 20 : 10 )
                    .offset(x: isShowing ? 300 : 0,y:isShowing ? 44 :0)
                    .scaleEffect(isShowing ? 0.8 : 1)
                    .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
                        withAnimation(.spring()){
                            isShowing.toggle()
                        }
                    }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "list.bullet")
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                    }))
                    .navigationTitle("home")
            }
//        }
    }
}
```

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: if I want to navigationBarItems replace the back, and keep back to the previous page function,is this workable?

Comment: @黃冠維 For such a function, I recommend using a modal view with `.sheet()` or `fullScreenCover()`. Because the dismiss function can be used in the modal view, the customization of the back button can be varied. If my answer worked for you, please check my answer :D

Comment: @Teaeeun Kim Excuse me,I use your answer,I don't need to change the trailing part,it can work with the leading part.
But now I have four screen,it can't work with the leading part.

Comment: @黃冠維 Can you explain in more detail? Exactly what view flow you want and what kind of UI design do you want.

Comment: @Teaeeun Kim I upload my github link [github](https://github.com/simpson0826/swifttest2.git)
Now,I have four screen,At the SwiftUIView_map.swift in navigationBarItems part use trailing is work,but use trailing isn't work

Comment: @黃冠維 As long as you use the NavigationView, the navigation back button is always fixed at the top left. You can hide it with `.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)`, but you need to make custom back button somewhere then.